# How to use hapi-swaggered without a running server

Tags: hapi.js

I have a working hapi service, complete with hapi-swaggered and hapi-swaggered-ui.  This is useful for many cases, but I want to add a build step to my CI which will be able to get the JSON generated by hapi-swaggered (which, if changed, would get compiled that into an .Net assembly that gets stored in a local proget).

I know that if I really wanted to, on my build server, I could start an instance of my server, `curl` to `localhost:3000/swagger`, kill the server, and proceed, but that seems a little risky (i.e., what if I have two builds running at the same time?).

Has anyone developed a way to directly call the hapi-swaggered API to get the raw JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that didn't take too much longer, but I think I found one solution.  In this case, `internals` is my server.  It does not auto-start if its loaded (`required`'ed) from another file, and the `compose` method is exposed to use hapi's `Glue.compose` to assemble the service.  It seems that I can then use the `inject` method to simulate a call.

```
'use strict';

var internals = require('./');

internals.compose(function(err, server) {
    server.inject({ method: 'GET', url: '/swagger' }, function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.result));
        process.exit();
    });
});
```

If there's anything that I'm missing about this technique, I'd like to hear about it.